# How to create a selected html-select-option in a ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `<select>`-Element where the enclosed `<option>`-Tags are created with `ng-repeat`.

One of these `option`-Tags shall have the `selected`-attribute added, depending on a value, but I can't figure it out how to deploy the attribute in only one `option`.

This is the base code:

```
<select name="level" ng-model="srv.level">
  <option ng-repeat="level in DataService.getLevels()" 
     value="{{level.id}}">{{level.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and the result is already:

```
<select ng-model="srv.level" name="level" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="0" ng-repeat="level in DataService.getLevels()"
        class="ng-scope ng-binding">Level Zero</option>
    <option value="1" ng-repeat="level in DataService.getLevels()" 
        class="ng-scope ng-binding">Level Uno</option>
    <option value="2" ng-repeat="level in DataService.getLevels()"
        class="ng-scope ng-binding">Level Two</option>
</select>
```

Now I want that one of the `option`-Tags has the attribute `selected` depending on `level.id === srv.level`. How can I do that?

Here is a link to a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xMOQgaffBpqKaUCHRn3I)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/uwruchg1JjGib6dT4QB9?p=preview

```
 <select name="level" ng-model="srv.level.id" ng-options="level.id as level.name for level in data.getLevels() ">
      <option value='0'>--choose level--</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Perfect, this solution also allows the data binding to work, where as the one below doesn't. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<option ng-selected='level.id === srv.level'></option>`.

Thus, the option will be selected only if the predicate in `ng-selected` is true.